# How to specify condition that depends on a grouping variable in dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following dataset where I want to create a new column ("Attribute 2") and assign the values by another column ("Attribute 1") based on whether the sum of the value ("Value") equals 2 or more when grouped by the unique ID ("ID") .

For example, for ID = 1001 where:

- Attribute 1 = Red, therefore Attribute 2 = Group 3
- Attribute 1 = Blue & Value = 1 when grouped by ID, Attribute 2 = Group 1

For ID = 1002 where:

- Attribute 1 = Red, therefore Attribute 2 = Group 3
- Attribute 1 = Blue & Value >= 2 when grouped by ID, Attribute 2 = Group 2

I currently am using the following formula, but unsure how to to specify the "grouped by unique record" part.

```
a <- c("1001", "1001", "1002", "1002", "1002", "1003", "1004")
b <- c("Red", "Blue", "Red", "Blue", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow")
c <- c(NA, 1, NA, 1, 1, NA, NA)
df <- data.frame("ID" = a, "Attribute1" = b, "Value" = c)

df <- df %>%
   mutate(Attribute2 = case_when(
      Attribute1 == "Red" ~ "Group 3",
      Attribute1 == "Green" ~ "Group 3",
      Attribute1 == "Yellow" ~ "Group 3",
      Attribute1 == "Blue" & Value == 1 ~ "Group 1",
      Attribute1 == "Blue" & Value >= 2 ~ "Group 2"
   ))
```

| ID | Attribute1 | Value | Attribute2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Red | NA | Group 3 |
| 1001 | Blue | 1 | Group 1 |
| 1002 | Red | NA | Group 3 |
| 1002 | Blue | 1 | Group 2 |
| 1002 | Blue | 1 | Group 2 |
| 1003 | Green | NA | Group 3 |
| 1004 | Yellow | NA | Group 3 |

Comment: I have thousands of different records for my ID field. If I were to use group_by(ID), what's the best way to write the code so when I create "Attribute 2", it only applies to certain conditions of "Attribute 1"? For example, I need it grouped by ID when Attribute 1 = A and B, but not when Attribute 1 = C.

Comment: I have updated my original post with an example closer to my actual data.

Comment: If I understood correctly, I have written the code to provide the example data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Myabe this will help -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(sum_val = sum(Value, na.rm = TRUE), 
         Attribute2 = case_when(
           Attribute1 %in% c("Red", "Green", "Yellow") ~ "Group 3",
           Attribute1 == "Blue" & sum_val == 1 ~ "Group 1",
           Attribute1 == "Blue" & sum_val >= 2 ~ "Group 2"
         )) %>%
  ungroup()

#    ID Attribute1 Value sum_val Attribute2
#  <int> <chr>      <int>   <int> <chr>     
#1  1001 Red           NA       1 Group 3   
#2  1001 Blue           1       1 Group 1   
#3  1002 Red           NA       2 Group 3   
#4  1002 Blue           1       2 Group 2   
#5  1002 Blue           1       2 Group 2   
#6  1003 Green         NA       0 Group 3   
#7  1004 Yellow        NA       0 Group 3
```